# Is the next set closed with the strong topology, weak topology and weak topology*?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

$S=\{x=(x_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \ell^{1}: \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=0  \}$

I can show that S is closed with the strong topology and the weak topology.
I defined
$$ T: \ell^{1}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}  $$
where $T(x): \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_{n}=0$

I show that T is a continuous function, and $S=T^{-1}(\{0\})$ for that S is closed with the strong topology. Next I showt that S is a convex set and for that the strong clousure and the weak clousure are the same. I think that S is not closed with the weak topology* but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: Ask yourself whether $ \displaystyle (x_n)_{n\,\in\,\mathbb N} \mapsto \sum_{n\,=\,1}^\infty x_n$ is a continuous function, for each of the topologies in question. The inverse-image of a closed set under a continuous function is closed. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks, I already occupied that condition but I have problem to show that it is closed with the weak topology *. I think it isn't, but I can't find the counterexample

Answer (score 1):

It is not closed under weak-star convergence: Let $x_n:=e_1-e_n$. Then $x_n \rightharpoonup^* e_1$ in $l^1 = (c_0)^*$.

Comment: It should be noted that the weak$^\ast$ topology on $\ell^1$ is not well-defined since the space has several non-isomorphic preduals (not only $c_0$, but also $C(K)$ for any countable compact space $K$).